# How to group by value in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Currently, I can group data in Google Sheets like so:

[image]

Rows `2` and `3` are grouped above. I have a very large list, however, and want to do this automatically. Here's a simpler example:

```
ID | Value
1  | Red Apple
1  | Green Apple
2  | Strawberry
2  | Blackberry
2  | Raspberry
```

The rows `Red Apple`, `Green Apple` will be grouped together, while `Strawberrry`, `Blackberry`, and `Raspberry` will be grouped together.

Is this possible in Google Sheets?

Comment: Short answer: Yes, use Google Apps Script.

Comment: Have a look at [Google Apps Script: Google Sheet Grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50731722/1330560). It has the basics of looping and grouping.